# Unable to run bash script says ( xrealloc: cannot allocate 18446744072476425728 bytes (77824 bytes allocated)?

Tags: shell-script

Newbie to shell scripting, can someone help me in debugging the bash script. Suggestions please!

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

for i in *_R1_001_trimo.fastq
do
  SAMPLE=$(echo ${i} | sed "s/_R1_\001\_trimo.fastq//")
  echo ${SAMPLE}_R1_001_trimo.fastq
        for((k=11; k<=31; k++))
        do
                cmd="time /home/anaconda3/envs/shannon_env/bin/shannon_cpp shannon -l 100 -s /home/data/brain_samples/fastqgz/trim/test/${SAMPLE}_R1_001_trimo.fastq -o /home/data/brain_samples/fastqgz/trim/test/${SAMPLE}_R1_001_trimo_shan_${k}mer -t 5 -u 2 -g 50 -k ${k} -m 50G > /home/data/brain_samples/fastqgz/trim/test/${SAMPLE}_R1_001_trimo_shan_log”
echo ${cmd}
$cmd
echo “finish"
        done
done

**Error**
kmer1.sh: xrealloc: cannot allocate 18446744072476425728 bytes (77824 bytes allocated)
```

Comment: There is a typo in `echo “finish"`. Does that solve the problem?

Comment: Similar in `cmd="time ...”`.

Comment: The `SAMPLE=$(echo` can be replaced by `SAMPLE="${i/R1_001_trimo.fastq/}"`

Comment: Run the script as `bash -vx kmer1.sh` and add the output to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, the script is running too slow even I allocated 100 GB of RAM.

Comment: How do i speed up this process ?

Comment: *#!/bin/bash
set -e
for i in *_R1_001_trimo.fastq
do
  SAMPLE=$(echo ${i} | sed "s/_R1_\001\_trimo.fastq//")
  echo ${SAMPLE}_R1_001_trimo.fastq
        for((k=11; k<=31; k++))
        do
                cmd="time /home/anaconda3/envs/shannon_env/bin/shannon_cpp shannon -l 100 -s /home/data/brain_samples/fastqgz/trim/test/test1/${SAMPLE}_R1_001_trimo.fastq -o /home/data/brain_samples/fastqgz/trim/test/test1/${SAMPLE}_R1_001_trimo_shan_${k}mer -t 5 -u 2 -g 30 -k ${k} -m 100G > /home/data/brain_samples/fastqgz/trim/test/test1/${SAMPLE}_R1_001_trimo_shan_log" *

Comment: echo ${cmd}
$cmd
echo "finish"
        done
done